# Distributing TideSDK application

Tags: titanium, desktop-application, tidesdk

I recently finished an application based on Titanium, Javascript, HTML, CSS. I have only been a web designer to date so I have little experience in distributing applications. I was accustomed to the TiDev Community deploying app, which prepared the app for download and made it available for download at a given link.

But tidev community is no longer supported, so I use TideSDK Developer to package the app, which doesnt do all the hard work the other one did so nicely.
I am obviously a complete rookie to this.

Could anyone outline the steps I would need to take to go from the bundled application folder I have now (put together by TideSDK Developer), to a link that will allow customers to download and install the app or online? I know there is an issue with packaoging the app for platforms other than your own, and that appcelerator is working on a solution to this I think. I also realise I would probably have to pay to host the download online. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `tidebuilder.py` script. to compile a installation package. To compile a binary for a Mac, you must run the script on a Mac, to compile a binary for windows, you must be on a windows box etc.

[There is some documentation on how to use it here](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Packaging-TideSDK-apps) per platform. The command is very simple and works.

Once you have your application file (DMG for OSX or a MSI for Windows) then just distribute it however you see fit, email, putting it on your web server, whatever works for you.

Comment: So TideSDK developer doesnt do the same thing as packagiglng with tidebuilder.py does?

Comment: So do you already have an app created you just want to put it online?

Comment: I found the appliation file, created by tidesdk dev. I was unsure of file type (msi as u let me know abor) i was looking for. Thank u:)